# Node command doesnt work

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and when i use node hello.js command on terminal nothing happens. I installed the packages using sudo apt-get command. I don't know what is wrong. No error message or anything. I searched for my problem but couldnt find anything.

Comment: What's the content of the `hello.js`?

Comment: I just wrote console.log("Hello"); to test the command out @jgillich

Comment: Weird. What does `node -v` return?

Comment: On Ubuntu, you'll have to use `nodejs hello.js`. This is due to `node` already representing a different application, [as described in the installation guide](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu-mint-elementary-os): "*There is a naming conflict with the node package (Amateur Packet Radio Node Program), [...]*"

Comment: nodejs command worked. Does it have any difference with node or can i use it like i am using node command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem has to do with package naming. The `node` package in Debian/Ubuntu is **not** node.js, it's amateur packet radio software.

My suggestion is that if you want node.js, remove the existing `node` program (`sudo apt-get purge node` for Debian/Ubuntu) and follow the instructions [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/) for your particular distro/platform. That should get you the latest stable version, which you should be able to verify with `node -v`.

Comment: Someone suggested using nodejs and it worked. Would using it make any difference?

Comment: The `nodejs` package in the official Ubuntu repositories can become stale fairly quickly because of Ubuntu/Debian's policies on versions for stable OS releases. The reason I recommended the PPA was because that is a repository that is kept up to date with the latest stable node.js releases.