# node.js on vps - no result

Tags: node.js, putty, vps

So I installed node.js on my server, when I go through putty to catalog (using `cd` command), then use command `node myfile.js`, it doesn't do anything - any response, nothing. Same with just command `node`.
OS:     Ubuntu Server 15.04 x64

Comment: what do you see when you command node -v? or the content of hello.js?

Comment: Nothing. Any answer at all.

Comment: this is duplicated my friend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23372276/node-command-doesnt-work. more research please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20058007/772035